# cannot find the module

Tags: node.js, npm, module, npm-cli

```
 throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.16.1
```

i want a clear solution the methods seen are not solving my error

Answer (score 0):

You should also provide the code that you run that makes this error appear.

The `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` error indicates that you try to import a module that you didn't installed.